# Trying to save datenum

Tags: matlab, datetime, save

I have a small problem with saving the datenum in Matlab.
I have a sensors which reads data in real-time. Then I am adding the time when the reading was received by the computer.
I am constructing a matrix with first column time as given from function now, second column being the data. This is done in real-time in Matlab. Everything works perfect untill I have to save the data.

When saving data, the date is rounded automatically. If I plot now my time (da variable), I will get a function which increases.
However, If I plot mam(1,:), I get a flat line.
I have tried many things but with same result.

Do you know, how can I save the matrix (ma) in Matlab in such a way to preserve all the decimals from date?

Here is a small script simulating my problem:

```
s=0;
j=1;
for i=1:10
  s(j)=s(end)+i;
  da(j)=now;
  pause(1);
  j=j+1;
end

ma= [da; s];
dlmwrite('mam.dat',ma);
```

`

Comment: I don't see variable rounding when I run your script. Is it still present if you explicitly set the precision, e.g. `dlmwrite('mam.dat', ma, 'precision', 16)`?

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestion with precission, it works as I want.   I am sorry for my late reply, I waited for the e-mail confirmation of answers.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided works fine. This can be verified by looking at the difference between `ma(1,1)` and `ma(2,1)` with `ma(1,1) - ma(1,2)` which doesn't return 0.

The rounding is occurring when the data is displayed. By [default matlab displays 6 decimal places](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/format.html). The command `format('long')` will cause all decimal places to be displayed.

*Style note*:

The logic in your loop is a little odd, here is more *matlaby* way to do what you've written above

```
nSample = 10;
s = nan(nSample,1); % pre allocate arrays, much faster for big arrays
da = nan(nSample,1);

for i = 1:nSample
    if i==1
       s(i) = 1;
    else
       s(i) = s(i-1) + i;
    end
    da(i) = now;
end

ma = [da; s];
dlmwrite('mam.dat', ma);
```

Comment: Dear Slayton, Thank you for the suggestion to improve the code and for the use of format. I am still working to improve the matlaby

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the data with as much precision as stored in the variables, export to a binary MAT-file instead of textual files:

```
save mam.mat ma
```

Comment: Dear Amro, Thank you for the suggestion, all solution works, Again, I am sorry for my late repply, I have waited for the e-mail confirmation with answers. Thank you again to all of you for your helpfull suggestion.